# No puedo guardar el self.saldo en csv writer para guardar el saldo cuando cierre el programa

Tags: python-3.x

En la función def puntaje, puse un csv writer para que guarde el saldo final que se obtuvo a finalizar las operaciones de ingreso y retiro, pero al momento de usar la función me sale error y que el objeto no es iterable, ya le puse int(self.saldo), pero el error continua y me sale que el objeto no es iterable. Acá dejo el código:

```
import csv
class cuentaBancaria:
    def __init__(self, titular, numero_de_cuenta, saldo):
        self.titular = titular
        self.numero_de_cuenta = numero_de_cuenta
        self.saldo = saldo
        # Lista para los movimientos
        self.movimientos = []

    def inicio(self):
        # Ciclo infinito que únicamente se interrumpe al ingresar "fin"
        while True:
            inicios = input("¿Qué tramite quiere realizar?: ").lower()
            if inicios == "ingreso":
                ingreso = int(input("¿Cuánto dinero quiere ingresar?: "))
                mensaje = self.ingresos(ingreso)
            elif inicios == "retirar":
                retiro = int(input("¿Cuánto dinero quiere retirar?: "))
                mensaje = self.retiros(retiro)
            elif inicios == "saldo":
                mensaje = self.saldos()
            elif inicios == "consultar":
                # Revisar si hay movimientos
                if self.movimientos:
                    # Imprimir utilizando alineación de texto
                    print('Movimientos'.center(72, '-'))
                    # Recorrer todos los movimientos
                    for movimiento in self.movimientos:
                        # Imprimir utilizando alineación de texto para crear columnas
                        print(f'Tipo de movimiento: {movimiento[0]:<10} Cantidad: {movimiento[1]:>8}     Saldo: {movimiento[2]:>10}')
                    mensaje = 'Fin de los movimientos'.center(72, '-')
                else:
                    mensaje = 'No hiciste ningún movimiento'
                
            # Condición para terminar el ciclo infinito
            elif inicios == "fin":
                guardado = self.puntaje()
                # Finaliza el ciclo while
                break
            else:
                mensaje = "Esta opción no es válida"
                
            # Mostramos el mensaje obtenido de los métodos de la clase
            print(mensaje)
        return "Gracias por su visita"

    def ingresos(self, cantidad):
        self.saldo += cantidad
        # Agregar el ingreso a los movimientos
        self.movimientos.append(('Ingreso', cantidad, self.saldo))
        return f"Tu saldo es ahora de: {self.saldo}"

    def retiros(self, cantidad):
        if cantidad > self.saldo:
            mensaje =  "Ud no cuenta con el saldo suficiente"
        else:
            self.saldo -= cantidad
            mensaje = f"Tu saldo es ahora de: {self.saldo}"
            # Agregar el retiro a los movimientos
            self.movimientos.append(('Retiro', cantidad, self.saldo))
        return mensaje

    def saldos(self):
        return f"Tu saldo es: {self.saldo}"
    
    def datos(self):
        global datose
        return datose

    def puntaje(self):
        puntajes = self.saldo
        with open('puntaje.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
          writer = csv.writer(file)
          writer.writerows(puntajes)
    
mi_sueldo = cuentaBancaria("Juan", 199733051214, 1000)
print(mi_sueldo.inicio())
```

Además ya le puse int(self.saldo), puse en una variable el self.saldo y puse int(file), pero ninguna de esas opciones soluciono el error.Acá dejo como me sale el error, al momento de imprimir el código.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No utilices ```writer.writerows``` porque espera como argumento una lista o arreglo y self.saldo es simplemente un campo simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los archivos CSV contienen por los general datos separados por una coma (,) o algún otro separado prefijado.

Por ejemplo, una fila puede contener:

```
valor1,valor2,valor3
Valor1,valor2,valor2
...
```

Como observas cada fila tiene el aspecto de un arreglo:

```
reg=["valor1","valor2","valor2"]
```

De este modo puedes guardar el arreglo en una CSV utilizando:

```
writer.writerrow(reg)
```

Se utiliza *writerrow* porque voy a escribir un registro. Si tuviera que escribir más de uno como se indica líneas abajo, entonces, utilizo *writerrows*.

```
reg=[
     ["valor1","valor2","valor2],
     [valor1","valor2","valor2"]
]

writer.writerrows(reg)
```

En tu caso, estas intentando guardar un dato en un archivo delimitado. Un solo datos no forma una fila de datos, sin embargo, tampoco es una limitante. Si quieres guardar solo el dato, entonces, el saldo tendrás que pasarlo como un arreglo y utilizar *writerrow*:

```
writer.writerow([puntajes])
```

Comment: no se guarda el saldo usando writer.writerow([puntajes]), ya no sale el error, pero no se guarda el saldo.

Comment: Solo has reemplazar la línea del writerrows? Quizá necesite una columna adicional. *writerrow([puntajes," "])*. Igual déjame probarlo porque debería hacerlo. Porque pones newline="'?

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y si se guarda. La respuesta es correcta al problema que indicas.

Comment: solo he puesto el codigo que ha puesto arriba pero no se guardaba, manda el codigo porfa, porque no me sale

Comment: He copiado tu código y he puesto *writer.writerow([puntajes])* en reemplazo de *writer.writerows(puntajes)*. Lo ejecute, le dí *ingresar*, le puse 1000, le puse retirar y le puse 500 y finalmente le puse *fin*. Me creó el archivo *puntajes.csv* con 1500.

Comment: Ya remplace el código como lo has hecho pero no lo guarda, usted crea el archivo puntaje.csv primero, para que lo sobre escriba o eso aparece creado ??

Comment: Lo que hice es correr tu código tal cual con el cambio sugerido e hice lo que te explique en anterior correo y me creó el archivo. La verdad que no lo probé si es que existe el archivo. Lo voy a probar en este momento. En todo caso dime colo estas haciendo o probando. ¿Podrías borrar, si existe el archivo, y luego probar. Segundo, ¿podrías decirme, por favor , en que lugar quieres guardar el archivo.  Es decir,  el directorio. Quizs puedan ser problemas privilegios aunque no lo creo porque te hubiera salido error.

Comment: El archivo se crea solo si es que no existe. Lo que no probé si que pasa si ya existe. Ssupuestamente lo debe sobrescribir, pero en el mundo de la informática nunca se sabe.

Comment: mira este link: https://replit.com/@Jcguibovich/Puntajespy#main.py

Comment: Lo estoy probando en visual estudio y también lo probé block de notas con extensión py. Ya lo hice con un archivo csv existente en la misma carpeta que el archivo py y borrandolo. Quiero guardarlo en la misma carpeta que esta el archivo py, así lo havia hecho antes con otro código de tkinder,

Comment: Esta raro, ya me guardo el archivo csv cuando lo use con idle python, pero con visual estudio y usando block de notas con extensiones py no me funciona, no lo entiendo la verdad.

Comment: Por cierto sabes cómo guardar la cantidad se saldo para cuando lo cierre y lo vuelva a abrir el programa, así tenga el mismo saldo a cerrar y abrir el programa